# Get 404 when try open author page

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem when I try open root of author I get 404.

For example if I open url

```
http://example.com/author/author-1 - OK
http://example.com/author/ - 404 why?
```

I try to create page-author.php and resave permalink, but get same result. Also in rewrite rules default values

```
    object(WP_Rewrite)#3250 (24) {
  ["permalink_structure"]=>
  string(36) "/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/"
  ["use_trailing_slashes"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["author_base"]=>
  string(6) "author"
  ["search_base"]=>
  string(6) "search"
  ["comments_base"]=>
  string(8) "comments"
  ["pagination_base"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["comments_pagination_base"]=>
  string(12) "comment-page"
  ["feed_base"]=>
  string(4) "feed"
  ["front"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["root"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["index"]=>
  string(9) "index.php"
  ["matches"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rules"]=>
  NULL
  ["extra_rules"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
```

What I can do to see my author page ( author page with list of author )?

Comment: You are getting a 404 because the there is no parameter for the author page. I think you don't even have author page created in the back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **1) Make template**

Make a custom template and paste that PHP file into your themes directory with any name.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Author page */

// add header

/*
 * You can pass params to the function to get more control
 * like, exclude the admin, show full name etc.
*/

wp_list_authors( $args );

// add footer here
```

## **2) Make a new page and use template**

Let's say the name of the page is `http://example.com/author/` add the newly created template on this page.

Style this page as per your need. Good luck (Y)

**Don't have an idea how to use templates? Check this awesome tutorial [here]**[1](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/).

Reference [wp list authors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/)

Comment: Thank's I find problem it be in rewrite rules and not show my custom page.